# hide and show search view when clicked

Tags: android, searchview

In my project I created button and search view , I want to hide the searchview and show/visible when I clicked the button , how can I do that
this is xml code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/search"
   android:queryHint="Search .."
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>


<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="search"
   android:layout_below="@+id/search"
   android:textSize="16sp"
   android:id="@+id/but"/>
```

And this is java code

```
  final SearchView se=findViewById(R.id.search);
    Button bt = findViewById(R.id.but);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

I try to write setvisible methode but i can't find it in android 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `boolean` parameter named `flag` in code

```
boolean flag = false;
```

Check for the boolean value in onClick to hide/unhide searchview

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       if (flag){
         // means true
         serchview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         flag = false; 
       }
       else{
         serchview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) 
         flag = true;
       }  

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using your search view and button on toolbar, you can use search view at menu.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/miLocationsListSearch"
    android:icon="@drawable/icn_search"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu.search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

or

```
 bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      if(se.getVisiblity()==View.Visible)
          se.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      else
          se.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```